# Logstash Grok Parsing Failed

Tags: logstash, regular-expressions, grok

I need to match this entry

```
2015/10/30 23:58:21 pid 22223 testuser@testserver.example.com 192.168.0.1 [p4/2012.2/LINUX26X86_64/536738] 'test-monitor show'
```

To match this I wrote this Regex

```
P4_DATE (?>\d\d){1,2}\/(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(?:(?:0[1-9])|(?:[12][0-9])|(?:3[01])|[1-9])
P4_TIME (?:2[0123]|[01]?[0-9])\:(?:[0-5][0-9])\:(?:(?:[0-5]?[0-9]|60)(?:[:.,][0-9]+)?)
P4_PID \b(?:[1-9][0-9]*)\b
P4_USER \b\w+\b
P4_HOSTNAME \b(?:[0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z-]{0,62})(?:\.(?:[0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z-]{0,62}))*(\.?|\b)
P4_IP (?<![0-9])(?:(?:[0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])[.](?:[0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])[.](?:[0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])[.](?:[0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]))(?![0-9])
```

and then overall

```
 P4_MATCH %(P4_DATE:p4date} %{P4_TIME:p4time} pid %{P4_PID:p4pid} %{P4_USER:p4user}\@%{P4_HOSTNAME:p4client} %{P4_IP:p4remoteclient} [%{DATA:p4version}] \'%{DATA:p4action}\'" }
```

and then match via

```
match => [ "message", "%{P4_MATCH}" ]
```

But still getting "_beats_input_codec_plain_applied, _grokparsefailure"

I am not a regular expression expert but any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the specific issue, but take a look at https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/ -- build up your patterns one field at a time and see what step causes matching to fail.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting approach. The Grok library that comes with Logstash has some [prebuilt patterns](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/v4.0.0/patterns/grok-patterns) to help you avoid having to build large regexes like you're doing there. You may have better luck reusing their engineering than building your own.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in `p4date` where there is a bracket instead of a curly brace on the field it should be `%{P4_DATE:p4date}`.

You need to escape the square brackets for `p4version` which should be `\[%{DATA:p4version}\]`

There are extra characters `" }` after the `p4action` which need removing .

**THIS**

`P4_MATCH %(P4_DATE:p4date} %{P4_TIME:p4time} pid %{P4_PID:p4pid} %{P4_USER:p4user}\@%{P4_HOSTNAME:p4client} %{P4_IP:p4remoteclient} [%{DATA:p4version}] \'%{DATA:p4action}\'" }`

**SHOULD BE THIS**

`P4_MATCH %{P4_DATE:p4date} %{P4_TIME:p4time} pid %{P4_PID:p4pid} %{P4_USER:p4user}\@%{P4_HOSTNAME:p4client} %{P4_IP:p4remoteclient} \[%{DATA:p4version}\] \'%{DATA:p4action}\'`